# Argument of type X is not assignable to parameter of type X error in Angular 7

Tags: typescript, model, angular7

I have two models named "UserBook" and "Comment".

Book Model:
book_comments is an array of type Comment

```
export class UserBook {
    id: number;
    book_name: string;
    book_comments: Array<Comment[]>;

    constructor(book) {
        this.id = book.id ? book.id : null;
        this.book_name = book.name ? book.name : null;
        this.book_comments = [];
    }
}
```

Comment Model:

```
export class Comment {
    id: number;
    comment: string;
    date: string;

    constructor(comment) {
        this.id = comment.id ? comment.id : null;
        this.comment = comment.comment ? comment.comment : null;
        this.date = comment.date ? comment.date : null;
    }
}
```

I want to create a new Comment and push it into UserBook's comments array

```
book: UserBook;

postNewComment(comment): any {

    return this.http.post(environment.api + '/book/comments', {comment: comment}).pipe(
        tap(
            (response) => {
                this.book.book_comments.unshift(new Comment(response['comment']));
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            }
        )
    );

}
```

But I see this error.

"Error: Argument of type Comment is not assignable to parameter of type Comment"

If I change type of the book_comments to "any" then it works.

But I couldn't understand why it doesn't accept type Comment[]. Can anyone help me about that.

Comment: You may be confused between `Comment` and `Comment[]`. Find out what it returns first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one possible solution. You have declared an Array of T where T is also an array. So either unshift in an array of Comment[], or try what I did below simplified with no backend call.

```
import { Component, OnChanges, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

    class UserBook {
      id: number;
      book_name: string;
      book_comments: Array<Comment> = [];

      constructor(book) {
        this.id = book.id ? book.id : null;
        this.book_name = book.name ? book.name : null;
      }
    }

    class Comment {
      id: number;
      comment: string;
      date: string;

      constructor(comment) {
        this.id = comment.id ? comment.id : null;
        this.comment = comment.comment ? comment.comment : null;
        this.date = comment.date ? comment.date : null;
      }
    }

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-home',
      templateUrl: './home.component.html',
    })
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

      book: UserBook;

      public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.book = new UserBook({ id: 123, name: 'My Book' });
        this.book.book_comments.unshift(new Comment({ id: 1, comment: 'Hello World' }));
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. Your answer helped me to find my mistake. I am using the last version of WebStorm. Old versions was adding the import lines automatically when I right the name of a model. But I noticed that the new version has some bugs. It worked when I add the import line of the comment model manually. Thanks again..